# How to Format a string to be a part of URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to remove all chars that cant be part of urls, like spaces ,<,> and etc.

I am getting the data from database.
For Example if the the retrieved data is: Product #number 123!

the new string should be: Product-number-123

Should I use regex? is there a regex pattern for that?
Thanks

Comment: I take it you want an SEO-friendly string; not a data-preserving (uri-escaped) string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy regex to do this is:

```
string cleaned = Regex.Replace(url, @"[^a-zA-Z0-9]+","-");
```

Comment: Yes, this is fairly simple, perhaps follow it up with a replace of consecutive "-". Off the top of my head something like: 
`cleaned = Regex.Replace(cleaned, @"--+","");`
should do the trick.

Comment: Edited the answer to include my suggestion as it checked out. Hope you don't mind :)

Comment: I wouldn't mind if your edit is correct, but it isn't. My original regex replacement never produces consecutive dashes.

Comment: This yields "too many" hyphen characters in certain situations, including when you want to spell the name "O'Donnel".

Answer (score 2):

Here is a an example on how to generate an url-friendly string from a "normal" string:

```
public static string GenerateSlug(string phrase)
{
    string str = phrase.ToLower();

    str = Regex.Replace(str, @"[^a-z0-9\s-]", ""); // invalid chars       
    str = Regex.Replace(str, @"\s+", " ").Trim(); // convert multiple spaces into one space
    str = str.Substring(0, str.Length <= 45 ? str.Length : 45).Trim(); // cut and trim it
    str = Regex.Replace(str, @"\s", "-"); // hyphens

    return str;
}
```

You may want to remove the trim-part if you are sure that you always want the full string.

[Source](http://www.intrepidstudios.com/blog/2009/2/10/function-to-generate-a-url-friendly-string.aspx)

Comment: Might be worth doing a replace for Multiple hyphens too at the end of the above or you can end up with my----name----is type urls.

Comment: Is this a problem in other strings than strings that allready have hyphens? "my- --name- -is"

Comment: This seems like a very complicated piece of code to accomplish something that can be done with a single regex replace.

Comment: It's not that complicated, just verbose. And much easier to read than a single regex-replace.

Answer (score 1):

To just perform the replacement of special characters like "<" you can use `Server.UrlEncode(string s)`. And you can do the opposite with `Server.UrlDecode(string s)`.

Comment: Looks like he's after a human readable (aka SEO) friendly url rather than one that includes all the extra characters. Though this would work but would not be all that readable.

Comment: That's a fair point. I obviously missed that part of the question.